# AngularJS Form/HTTP/CORS

Tags: javascript, angularjs, forms, rest, http

I have an Angular form connected to a REST API to insert a new row to a MySQL database. My REST API is working, but I am getting a CORS blocked notice in my web console. How can I get it to successfully send to the REST PI? Below is my controller code code:

```
countryApp.controller('AddLocation', function ($scope, $http) {   

       $scope.orglocation = {}; 
        //
        $scope.submit = function() { 

          var dataObj = { 
              location_title : $scope.location.location_title, 
              location_latitude : $scope.location.location_latitude, 
              location_longitude : $scope.location.location_longitude          
          } 

          //convert data to JSON string
          var loc = JSON.stringify(dataObj); 

          $http.post('http://localhost/slimtest2/add_location', loc).
             success(function(data, status, headers, config) {
                alert("good"); 
             }).
             error(function(data, status, headers, config) {
                 alert("bye"); 
             });

       } 

       $scope.reset = function() { 
          $scope.location = angular.copy($scope.orglocation);   
       } 

   });
```

Comment: Is your Angular app hosted on another port?

Answer (score 0):

Generally when you hit a CORS problem it is a sign that your server is not configured correctly. I highly suggest looking at the [MDN article](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Access_control_CORS) on HTTP access control. The two headers that are most important to have in this case are:

- access-control-allow-origin
- access-control-allow-methods

Make sure the first is set to the domain and port you use to access your Angular app and that the second is set to the methods you use (in this case, at least POST).

Comment: will read up on it. It's a bit weird, on the same server my GET calls are working.